# JS in C# Form WebBrowser Get UI Stuck?

Tags: javascript, c#, multithreading, winforms

Running Javacript code in C# Windows Form WebBrowser. Need it to be able to run long time loop without getting the form UI stuck. Any ideas how? Or other ways to run JS to achieve this

Code:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
    public void ExecuteJS(WebBrowser wb)
    {

        // Create the webpage, testing a long loop to check UI stuck or not
        wb.DocumentText = @"<html>
            <head>
                <title>Test</title>
            </head>
            <body>
            <script>
            function TestInvoke() {
            while (true) {
            window.external.AnotherMethod('Hello');
            wait(2500);
            }
            }

            function wait(ms){
            var start = new Date().getTime();
            var end = start;
            while(end < start + ms) {
            end = new Date().getTime();
            }
            }
            </script>
            </body>
            </html>";
    }
}
```

Called (On a thread, which it is still making the UI stuck):

```
 private void BottingThread()
    {
        //run the js script
        this.Invoke(new Action(() => { webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("TestInvoke").ToString(); }));
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript code runs on one thread so you can't do that. Instead you can use [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) which periodically calls a function like so:

```
<script>

function TestInvoke() {
    setInterval(function() {
        window.external.AnotherMethod('Hello');
    }, 2500);
}

</script>
```

**Start/Stop logic:**

`setInterval` can be stopped using [`clearInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval). `setInterval` will return a handle/id that you need to pass to `clearInterval` when you want to stop. An example of how both can be used to start/stop a loop:

```
var interval = null;                           // the id of the current loop (initially set to null to indicate that no loop is in progress)

function start() {                             // the function that starts the loop
    if(interval !== null) {                    // first let's check that there aren't any loops already running
        clearInterval(interval);               // if so stop them first
    }

    interval = setInterval(function() {        // then start a loop and store its id in interval
        // code to be looped
    }, 2500);                                  // specify the delay between each iteration
}

function stop() {                              // the function that stops the loop
    if(interval !== null) {                    // if a loop is in progress
        clearInterval(interval);               // ... stop it
        interval = null;                       // and set interval to null to indicate that no loop is running
    }
}
```

Comment: In the end I want to be able to let the user write JS code that will loop all the time until he press "STOP BOTTING" which will terminate the loop. I don't think setInterval will help me here? Get what I mean? Or will it help me?

Comment: @Naveh `setInterval` can be stopped whenever you want. When you call `setInterval`, it will return a handle, just store that handle like: `var interval = setInterval( ... );` and when you want to stop it use [`clearInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval) like so: `clearInterval(interval);`

Comment: @Naveh I added an example of how start/stop functionality could be achieved using `setInterval`/`clearInterval`

Comment: Thank you very much sir! You helped me a lot, I was googling a fix for this problem around 3 days and didn't find anything. Much respect.

Comment: @Naveh You're welcome! Glad I could help! Happy coding : )